# Is 3DES outdated for message authentication code computing?

Tags: encryption, algorithm

I am working in IT department of a bank, currently we use 3DES to compute MAC of packet, is that safe enough using 3DES? Should we use any other more modern algorithm?

Comment: Have you done some research on the topic? There are many concerns but NIST deems it 'acceptable' (in some definition) for the moment.

Comment: How do you use 3DES? CBC MAC?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

3DES is a fine block cipher. The best known attack has academic cost 2<sup>112</sup>, which is way beyond the technologically feasible. The main issue with 3DES is that it works on too small blocks (8 bytes, instead of 16 like AES), but that is not necessarily a problem in a specific situation.

3DES is still an encryption system, so if it is used as [MAC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Message_authentication_code) then this must be part of some sort of construction that provides a MAC out of a block cipher, e.g. [CBC-MAC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CBC-MAC). 3DES is fine for CBC-MAC, as long as no stupid thing was done in the implementation (in particular, it is of paramount importance that the key used for 3DES in CBC-MAC is *not* used also for encrypting data). Short blocks imply that you would prefer not to try to process more than about 32 gigabytes of data with a given key -- probably not an issue in your case.

If 3DES is used in some other custom, homemade construction, then anything goes. Homemade schemes tend to be awfully weak, in some horribly creative ways. But note that the weakness would be the construction, not 3DES itself.

Comment: "The best known attack" only "has academic cost $2^112$" when using a definition of academic cost that I've never seen, or when the 3DES is 3-key [rather than 2-key](http://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/2466/991).  "Short blocks imply that you would prefer" to limit each key to processing _much less than_ "about 32 gigabytes of data", (... continued)

Comment: (continued ...) since the [forgery probability will already exceed 27% before reaching 32 gigabytes](http://cseweb.ucsd.edu/~mihir/papers/cbc.pdf#page=30).  Also, another important thing for CBC-MAC is making sure that _either_ all the messages it will get used for will have the same length as each other _or_ the possibility of [length variability](http://cseweb.ucsd.edu/~mihir/papers/cbc.pdf#page=32) is properly handled.

Answer (score 2):

The exact answer depends on the nature of the data you handle and how you go about it.

3DES has been considered weak for some years now: machine have existed for several years that can break a single DES encryption [in about a day](http://www.sciengines.com/company/news-a-events/74-des-in-1-day.html).

Still, [in the current state of affairs as publicly known](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triple_DES#Security), the best attack against 3DES (using keying option 1 which means 3 different 3DES keys) with known plaintext still requires 2^32 known plaintext messages (which seems to be what you're talking about) and a considerable amount of time (2^112) and memory (2^88 bytes).

So, if I go out on a leg here and assume that

1. You're using 3DES with keying option 1 for message authentication.
2. AND You have a mechanism in place to change these keys on a semi-regular basis (once a year, maybe).
3. AND You're not going to use these MACs to certify the authenticity of your messages in many years in the future, you should be safe against currently know attacks.

Comment: thanks, I don't know much about this topic, but according to your answer, it's safe for us, as we change the keys every half hour.

Answer (score 0):

According to http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triple_DES it's probably more than acceptable. You can always choose something else if you feel the level of security is not acceptable.

Answer (score -1):

In my opinion, it is not so safe. 3 rounds with 56b key gives us algorithm strength equal to 192b, but when we consider "Meet in the middle" attack strength decreases to 112b.

Comment: NIST disagrees with you, and they deem the security to be 80b (lower than your 112b). It all depends on the application. Can you elaborate on why you think 112b is not safe?